# how to modify message when using node-http-proxy to proxy websocket

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, node-http-proxy

ATT.

I'm using `node-http-proxy` to proxy to websocket,

but how can I modify message before send to backend websocket server?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?